# Ctrl + Space not showing any suggestion in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am facing a problem for my macbook in VS Code, which is I am not getting any suggestions for my TypeScript IntelliSense.

```js
type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

const user:User = {
//If I press "ctrl+space" I am expecting to get the suggestions. Which is not happening.
}
```

Am I expecting things wrong? Or is something wrong?

Comment: It might help if you share a bit more information about your settings configuration. There might be a "turn it off and on again" solution, resetting the IDE or resetting the computer itself might fix your problem.

Comment: I am doing everything written in here. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense
The eidtor setting actually. I am also sure, may be something is off. But if so then `.` is how working?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I just found this happen on windows 11 with PowerTools (v0.70) installed. The peek feature is hijacking ctrl + space

Comment: I can confirm this (v0.70 on Win11). Disabling Peek in PowertTools solves the problem.

Comment: @Mart Gregory, you saved my life, dude! This is it! Just change your Peek shortcut or disable it if you don't need it and the Ctrl+Space suggestion in VS Code starts working again!

Comment: I was seeing the same thing in Android Studio.  Added an Answer that includes screenshots / steps to disable PowerToys Peek feature here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444491/why-did-ctrlspace-autocomplete-suddenly-stop-working-in-android-studio-intel/76444492#76444492

Comment: It's the best. Thank you very much. I had PowerToy installed on all my computers and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 49):

In my case there was a native OSX shortcut shadowing CTRL+Space.

First check that the completion is effectively working by writing a dot "." after an object or opening a parenthesis after a function name.

If this works then try deactivating the OSX shortcut by going to Preferences > > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Input sources > Select the previous input source

Restart VSCode.

Comment: Legend! This worked for me after lots of frustration. It might be a MacOS Ventura issue. I have never turned that shortcut on.

Comment: I believe it activated after I tried to add another language to the keyboard. Even if I reverted it, it still left those input shortcuts active. Thanks for saving me time!

Comment: This fixed it for me! I'm running VSCode v1.79.2 and macOS Venture 13.4.

Comment: Yep, worked for me! (For those like me, dont go to preferences, settings ... in VSCode, its in Mac settings)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It worked for me on Ventura 13.5.2, VSCode 1.84 and keyboard G213. I had never set that shortcut on, they have probably being set installing Logitech G Hub.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for many reasons,

### 1. Check for Errors

If you have any syntax or eslint errors, fix those then try ctrl space.

### 2. Restart Typescript server

If you have no syntax errors, then you can restart typescript server by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P and typing "Restart typescript server" then press enter. If you have no such option then try restarting VS Code itself and check if it works.

Hope this helps

Comment: No didn't work. The project has its `tsconfig.json` but doesn't have globally installed `typescript` on my machine. Is this could be a reason?

Comment: yes install typescript

Comment: npm install typescript --save-dev

Comment: And yet not working.

Comment: It does work if I am console logging or `after (.)` operator