# Editor doesn't detect ctrl+d

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, windows-11

I had set the ctrl+d shortcut for the delete row command on Visual Studio Code (like Eclipse default shortcut) and I've used it for years.

Suddenly it stopped working on both editors: I checked the Eclipse shortcut list and ctrl+d is set for delete line, but when I press ctrl+d nothing happens.

On VS Code, I tried to disable all extensions and resetting shortcouts and I also notice that it seems as if pressing ctrl+d is not detected, while ctrl+ any other key is detected and works. So, I had to set again ctr+d shortcut manually by add it in keybindings.json, but it doesn't actually work.
I tried to so Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting and when I press, for example, ctrl+a, in the output section:

```
2024-01-08 11:28:51.456 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-01-08 11:28:51.456 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-01-08 11:28:51.456 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2024-01-08 11:28:51.456 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2024-01-08 11:28:51.456 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-01-08 11:28:51.656 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-01-08 11:28:51.656 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+A
2024-01-08 11:28:51.656 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.selectAll, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
2024-01-08 11:28:51.657 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyA, keyCode: 65, key: a
2024-01-08 11:28:51.657 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyA, keyCode: 31 ('A')
2024-01-08 11:28:51.657 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+A
2024-01-08 11:28:51.657 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.selectAll, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
2024-01-08 11:28:51.657 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.selectAll.
2024-01-08 11:28:52.127 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

Ctrl+d press:

```
2024-01-08 11:29:12.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-01-08 11:29:12.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-01-08 11:29:12.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2024-01-08 11:29:12.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2024-01-08 11:29:12.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-01-08 11:29:12.776 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

So only ctrl is detected.

I mainly use VS Code so it would be important to resolve for it, but the fact that it also stopped working on Eclipse makes me think it's not an editor problem.

I'm using:
Windows 11 Enterprise, version 22H2
Visual Studio Code version: 1.85.1 (user setup)
Eclipse version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)

Comment: That sounds like Windows or another system tool like [Microsoft PowerToys](https://mastodon.social/@howlger/110462282002158739), a tool for your graphic card or something else catches this shortcut. You can verify this in Eclipse by going to the preferences _General > Keys_, setting the focus into the _Binding:_ field and typing Ctrl+D. If Ctrl+D is not displayed, something else catches the shortcut.

Comment: It's exactly as you say: both vs code and eclipse don't detect ctrl+d, but only ctrl. I don't know what is intercepting it and how to fix it

Comment: Which system tools have you recently installed, updated or changed?

Comment: I don't think I've installed, updated or changed something. Is there a way to understand who is detecting and blocking the shortcut?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to find out what is catching Ctrl+D. You can try to exit the tools that are shown in the taskbar and see whether Ctrl+D in Eclipse and VS Code will start working again. If this does not help, the Task Manager shows which processes are running. You can also try to do a web search with "Ctrl+D" and the name of the tools you have installed. Is something happening when you hit Ctrl+D when no application is running?

Comment: related? https://superuser.com/q/92263/1749748

Comment: I don't have the program mentioned in the post. Other colleagues of mine are also experiencing the same problem as me suddenly, we'renot understanding why

Comment: Maybe Webex, see [VS Code issue #201151](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201151).

Comment: It looks just like webex: I tried closing it from the task manager and now ctrl+d works, maybe it did some automatic updating without me realizing it. There's a setting in Webex that you can turn off to resolve this issue. Thank you both so much for helping me understand the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did good with troubleshooting your keybindings. At the point you got to, you'd need to figure out what other software is consuming the keypress. Check your OS / desktop-environment keyboard shortcuts, and check the keyboard shortcuts of other running programs. You could try temporarily disabling your OS-level startup programs and then restarting the machine to see if it's being consumed by one of the startup programs, and then start each program one by one to find out which one is causing it.

In this case, it was found to be caused by WebEx. You can remove the WebEx keybinding `"Decline Call" - CTRL+D - Global yes`. See issue ticket [CTRL+D keyboard shortcut not working on Windows
#201151](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201151).

Other examples of conflicts include one caused by PowerToys (see [Ctrl + Space not showing any suggestion in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74533980/11107541)), or Screenshot Studio (see https://superuser.com/q/92263/1749748).